# Is there a way to list all Cucumber step definitions

Tags: cucumber-jvm

The list of all of the expressions of Step Definitions (methods with `@Given` `@When` or `@Then` annotations) effectively defines the ubiquitous language that is available to be used to write Steps within Scenarios.

I have found myself loosing track of existing Step Definitions, and I have created different variants of existing Step Definitions with slightly different expressions.  I have had to go back and refactor a number of times to eliminate duplicates.  If only I had known about the original Step Definition in the first place ...

Is there an automated way of getting a list of all Step Definition expressions, preferably separated by the class they are in?

The expressions from annotations are what I specifically need, but bonus if it also works using Java 8 lambda means of defining Step Definitions.

Comment: Hello. Did you even find the answer on your question? I try to find same answer and it is strange there is no easy answer on this

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk Sadly, not yet. I am a little behind on Cucumber versions (upgrade fatigue!), but I haven't seen any indication of any new feature that would provide this. I imagine it would be possible to write a tool or a [Cucumber reporting plugin](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/?lang=java) to provide this, maybe somewhat similar to the [unused steps plugin](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/01/cucumber-jvm-plugin/).  It would also be nice to list the `ParameterType` entries (including name and regular expression) that define new Cucumber Expression.

Comment: There is also a [How to implement a Cucumber-JVM plugin](https://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2019/03/07/how-to-implement-a-cucumberjvm-plugin) blog that would be useful.